# opendir() failed to open dir, not impemented in

Tags: php, warnings, slideshow, opendir

I'm trying to write some php to make an image slideshow from a file on a server. When I try to opendir it gives me the error in the title

```
$images = glob('*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
$count = count($images);
$var_count = $count + 1;

$arr_img = Array();
$handle = opendir('http://dev2.matrix.msu.edu/~matrix.training/Holmberg_Dane');
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
 if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
    $arr_img[] = $file;
 }
}
```

Comment: check for the real error and rtm http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php

Answer (score 3):

You can't call `opendir()` on an HTTP address. HTTP doesn't have the concept of "directories" (unless you count WebDAV).

Comment: So how do I reach the directory that I need from the server?

Comment: @daneholmberg Either make the server read the directory itself and return the contents in a machine-readable format like JSON, or (assuming your server is actually set up to automatically produce an Apache directory listing) parse the HTML directory listing outputted by the server.